# Error "React will try to recreate this component tree from scratch using the error boundary you provided, ErrorBoundary." in NextJS app + 404 page

Tags: next.js, error-handling, custom-error-pages, react-error-boundary

I have a NextJS app. In the app, I have a custom 404 page that I literally took from https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-error-page. I also have a `middleware.ts` file that checks for authentication. My NextJS app uses the `getStaticPaths` and `getStaticProps`. I have set `fallback` to `false` in my `getStaticPaths`.

When I run my app, and I go to a valid URL, my app renders the content correctly. However, when I am going to an INVALID URL, my app renders my custom 404 page briefly and then the browser console throws this error: `React will try to recreate this component tree from scratch using the error boundary you provided, ErrorBoundary.` along with some other errors like `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'default')`. Please see the images below.

When debugging I noticed that if I remove the `middleware.ts` file there are no errors. However,

1. if I have the `middleware.ts` file and using the default NextJS 404 page I get an infinite requests for a 404 page in my Network tab.

[image]

2. if I have the `middleware.ts` file and use the custom 404 page I get the below errors.

[image: Unhandled Runtime Error]

[image: Uncaught TypeError]

As you can see in the above image, the 404 page is loaded briefly which is what is expected, but immediately it throws the other errors.

[image: MDXRemote component error]

Firstly, I have not set any `ErrorBoundary` in my NextJS app.

Secondly, I thought that if `fallback` is `false` everything not matching the paths from the `getStaticPaths` will be 404 without even calling the component. So, I am getting confused why I am getting the above errors.

I believe there is something happening with the authentication set up in the `middleware.ts` file. Do I need to add anything more related to my custom `404.tsx` page in my `getStaticProps`?

Any help would be appreciated as I am new to NextJS. Not sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my `package.json` I was using `"next": "13.1.6"`. After referring to https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/43953 and https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/44293 I figured maybe my current next package was causing the issue. So, all I did was upgraded my next package to  `"next": "13.2.1"` and everything started working correctly.